# jQuery Multiple Select val

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a character count-down from 2 textareas in the same div class 'fields'. My code works fine for just 1 textarea but it doesn't work at all if i try to select 2:

```
function wordCount()
{   

    var num = 100 - $("#id_COMMENT_PRO,#id_COMMENT_NEG").val().length;
    if (num < 0) {
        num = 0;
        }

    $('#count').text('Words left: ' + num);


}
```

and here's where I'm calling it in my form:

```
$(function () { $('#id_COMMENT_PRO').keyup(function() { wordCount(); }); $('#id_COMMENT_NEG').keyup(function() { wordCount(); }) } );
```

Apologies if its obvious but I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: try 100 - ($("#id_COMMENT_PRO).val().length + $("#id_COMMENT_NEG).val().length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only return one val, which is why this wont work. Try this:

```
var num = 100 - $("#id_COMMENT_PRO").val().length - $("#id_COMMENT_NEG").val().length;
```